# How can to make it run until user enters 0 or negative number?

Tags: java, loops

I would love to know how to make it run until user enters 0, i tried doing while (i <=number) && (number != 0) but it didnot work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String args[]){
          int i =1, factorial=1, number;
          System.out.println("Enter the number to which you need to find the factorial:");
          sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          number = sc.nextInt();

          while (i <=number) {
             factorial = factorial * i;
             i++;
          }
          System.out.println("Factorial of the given number is:: "+factorial);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make it run until a user enters 0"? The program terminates when it finishes calculating the factorial. Do you want it to keep accepting new factorials until the user quits?

Comment: Yes Matthew i cant figure out

Comment: See my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize number to a non-zero integer and enclose everything in a while loop.

```
public class Main {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int number = 7; // can just use a random starting number which is not 0
        while (number != 0) { // Add a while loop to make it keep asking for factorials until 0 is given to quit
            int i = 1, factorial = 1;
            System.out.println("Enter the number to which you need to find the factorial or enter 0 to quit:");
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            number = sc.nextInt();

            while (i <= number) {
                factorial = factorial * i;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("Factorial of the given number is:: " + factorial);
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for using the factorial calculator. ");

    }
}
```